# How to nest two column from same table in category and subcategory Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have four column in table which I must nest in name_category and name_subcategory. Look my code

```
public function getCategory(){
       $categories =  DB::table('products')
        ->select(array('category','name_category', 'subcategory' , 'name_subcategory'))
        ->distinct('category', 'name_category', 'subcategory', 'name_subcategory')
        ->get();
        return response()->json($categories);
    }
```

Category is only code for name_category and reference for name_category, also subcategory is code for name_subcategory. I need nest all name_subcategory in name_category like a example, or similar

```
{ 
'name_category' : 'food'
'name_subcategory' : 'chicken',
'name_subcategory' : 'veal'
 }
{ 'name_category' : 'drink',
 'name_subcategory' : 'juice',
 'name_subcategory' : 'beer',
}
```

This category and subcategory fields is only reference code for article not important to show to response.

Comment: add parent_id column in table, in your sub category set the parent id of parent category id. or use this page to create nested columns https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: It is little hard option. I think have a better and little easy option.

Comment: Did anyone have better idea? Idea not must be same as  my json object...can be similar